# Crystal Reports with Blazor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, crystal-reports, blazor

I'm looking at converting an ASP.NET MVC program that includes Crystal Reports to Blazor, but Blazor runs with ASP.NET Core and Crystal Reports doesn't seem to support that.  Is there some way of running Blazor on the "full" .Net?  i.e., not ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. I'm using VS 2019 latest and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP 28.

When I installed the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio it didn't seem to recognize the Blazor server app project, I assume because it's an ASP.NET Core project.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports will not work with a Blazor application. You'll need to find another provider. I've quite enjoyed working with [QuestPDF](https://www.questpdf.com/). PowerBI may be something you could look at too.

However, as you've determined yourself, Crystal Reports cannot be used in conjunction with Blazor in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not Blazor per se but the dependency on COM.
Internally, the Crystal runtime uses COM objects, so it's anchored to the older .NET Framework (e.g. 4.8).

You can keep your existing Crystal logic on .NET classic and use Interprocess Communications.